# My date drives me crazy (Java)

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I need to convert a string to a Date object using `SimpleDateFormat`.

I use `"MMM. dd yyyy"` to parse strings like `"Dec. 30 2011"`, with 3 month char and a dot.

It fails for `"May 30 2011"` so I have to catch the exception and re-try with `"MMM dd yyyy"`. It works for "May", so far so ugly but works.

But when it get to "Sept. 11 2011", all of the above plus `"MMMM. dd yyyy"` and `"MMMM dd yyyy"` fail. So I can't parse it at all.

What is going on?

Comment: `design-patterns` tag is for something special?

Answer (score 4):

try this pattern -

> MMM'.' dd yyyy

Code -

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM'.' dd yyyy");
Date date = df.parse("Dec. 30 2011");
```

Hope it will help you to make fun :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried but no joy. The problem is with "Sept. 30 2011"

Comment: @user2720403 Try using 'MMMM'

Comment: `Sept. 30 2011` is not right representation of date string, I think string should be `Sep. 30 2011`.

Comment: So do I have to replace Sept. with Sep.? I tried MMMM, it doesn't work. Neither does MMMM., with the traing dot.

Comment: Either Sep or September. For Sep `MMM` and September `MMMMM`.

Comment: OK that is done and it works. I was expecting it to be a bit more intelligent. Well that is a real dumb date indeed.

Comment: -1 this is completely unhelpful. There is no way this will work. It would only parse "September. 11 2013"

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for your attention and comment, you could use either Sep or September. You need to use for Sep `MMM` and September `MMMMM` pattern and It works, I have tested Sir.

Comment: It does **not** work:. Here's the result of parsing using your format: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sept. 11 2013"`

Comment: As I said before, using "MMM'.'" will only parse "Sep.", not "Sept."

Comment: Sir, I have written that thing in comment, "Sept. 11 2013" is not write date representation, "Sep. 11 2013" and "September. 11 2013" are correct.

Answer (score 4):

If it were me, instead of trying different patterns and rely on exception handling, I would just substring the first 3 letters, append the last 7 letters, and parse it with `MMMdd yyyy`.

Comment: agree, that is a better way.

Comment: Agree, but do not forget to specify an english locale when parsing english month names, else you will get an error when running in a different default locale.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no out-of-the-box solution for tolerant date parsing. Neither JDK nor the often used Joda Time library support this directly. But it should be relatively easy to write a helper method that tries different date formats until it succeeds (or fails).

```
private static final DateFormat[] FORMATS = new DateFormat[] {
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM. dd yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd yy"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yy")  };

public static synchronized Date parse(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    ParseException e = null;

    for(DateFormat format : FORMATS) try {
        return format.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        if (e == null || e.getErrorOffset() < ex.getErrorOffset()) e = ex;
    }

    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java can only parse 3-letter abbreviations (as `MMM`) or full month names (as `MMMM`).

You must massage your input into a 3-letter abbreviation.  The simplest way is using regex.

Execute this line before parsing to clean it up:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=^...)\\w+\\.?", "");
```

This will give up you `Sep 11 2011` from `Sept. 11 2011`, but leave already appropriate input untouched. It will also clean up any length abbreviation, with or without the full stop - it's versatile.

You can then parse it using you existing format string.